# What is the function of 當 in 當愛已成往事 ?

Tags: translation

I think 愛已成往事 is complete chinese sentence, that means: love already turned into sth. of the past.

Well, but how does the meaning changes when 當 is put in front of it to form 當愛已成往事 ?

Comment: When (love fades away). This is a dictionary lookup question.

Comment: thank you , is "dictionary lookup" a separate category here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

當 just means "When" in such usage.

Answer (score 2):

當 have different means in many sentence

As a time adverb,it can be same as "WHEN" "WHILE" "AS" ,without the time limitation just (AS) you use these three word.

in an article,comes with the mentioned means,當 always appear in first word on a sentence or middle of.

當我離開的時候，要好好照顧你自己。
As I leave,take good care by yourself.

要好好照顧你自己當我離開的時候。
Taking good care by yourself as I leave.

當 be a adverb and whole letters is 當作,means take....as..

把我當白痴嗎?
Do you take me as a Idiot?

把我當作白痴嗎?
Do you take me as a Idiot?

當 be a verb ,in this time ,the pronunciation of 當 sounds like "DOWN" just you say without nasal sound

and in traditional usage,

當鋪 "DOWN" "PUH"   means Pawnshop = a shop(鋪) of pawning

典當 "D-IAN" , "DOWN" means pawn in 典當 and it has been simplified to 當 in modern usage

他在當鋪將一些首飾典當成現金
He pawns some jewelry for cash in pawnshop

他將一些首飾當成現金
He pawns some jewelry for cash